# Electron app takes too much start up time

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron, wine, electron-packager

Electron-React app which uses rails api have been packaged using electron packager. When I click exe file, it takes more than 30 seconds to start. It shows white screens for more than 30 seconds. Is it normal for electron app to behave like that. My app size is 350 mb. But surprisingly when I packaged for Linux it's working fine. I used wine to package for windows from my Ubuntu. Does it causes this performance issue?

Comment: Have you tried packaging it natively? I've never had issues with start times on larger projects. Perhaps Wine is including the bottler in your app?

Comment: @NorianNyx I will let you know the results. Thank you.

Comment: @NorianNyx Yea maybe. i will let you know once i packaged it natively. i think it will work because when i packaged natively for linux, it was working fine.